# How to send a state variable of a component to the url of another page? (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

//Navbar.jsx

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState("")
const handleChange = (e) => {
setQuery(e.target.value) }
.
.
.
<input value={query} id="query" onChange={handleChange} />
```

Now my question is, I have a separate route ("/search/:query", component is Search.jsx). How do I send the 'query' state from the navbar to this route so that I can extract the query from the params and use it afterwards?

Basically it's a movie site and I have a search bar at the home page (in navbar) and a separate page for searching too but I want the search parameter in home page/navbar to be sent to that search page route for params extraction

I thought of prop sending but that wouldn't work since I'm sending data to the params of the url, so I'm pretty clueless

I am using react-router

Comment: Are you using react-router? How are you rendering different routes?

Comment: Yes, I am using react-router using Routes and Route, the search.jsx is in /search/:query, Home page is in "/"

Comment: You have search bar right, so after searching any movie hope you are showing the result and after click any of the result you want to move /search/:query page right ?

Comment: [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params#usesearchparams)

Answer (score 1):

-> Follow my code :-

->Navbar.jsx :-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setQuery(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Navigate to the search page with the query parameter
    history.push(`/search/${query}`);
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input value={query} id="query" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

-> In your Search.jsx component,you can access this query parameter using React router useParams hooks.

-> Search.jsx :-

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Search = () => {
  const { query } = useParams();

  // Use the query parameter in your component
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Search Results for: {query}</h1>
      {/* Render search results here */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use props. Use this in your search.jsx page:

```
const { query } = props.match.params;
```

now with a simple code you can get the data you want:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    searchFunction(query)
},[]);
```

if this doesn't work for you, try this:

```
const query  = this.props.location.state
```